# FFmpeg for fade in doesn't get applied to the final video

Tags: ffmpeg

This is the way I'm trying to apply fade in inside a filtercomplex of FFmpeg command.

```
[v]fade=t=in:s=0:n=30[vfadein]
```

This command doesn't return error but the result is a video without fade in effect. What's the problem?

Comment: What's the value of `startCut.ToString()`

Comment: Gyan thanks for the reply. It is 00:00:34.2210000

Comment: So your fade happens in the first 30 frames, but you only encode output from 34 seconds. Add a trim filter before the fade, `trim='00:00:34.221000'`.

Comment: and duration is `00:00:06.1600000`.

Comment: Gyan I've added this line to the command but the output is only audio no video `,[finalv]trim="+startCut.ToString()+ "[finalvtrimmed]"+`

Comment: What's your full cmd?

Comment: Thanks, it works. `[v]fade=t=in:st=34:n=30[vfadein]`